# Dust.js escape characters

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I am trying to print a newline and per the Dust.js guide, in the template I have a {~n} at the end of each record output

```
{#friends} {name}, {age}{~n}{/friends}
```

I compiled the above template and am rendering with a couple of JSON records to generate 'out' object. I am using the document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML to replace the 'out' object dynamically in a basic DIV tag. The problem is am not able to print newline inspite of the {~n}. I have also tried {~r}, but still not luck. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML collapses adjacent whitespace (including newline characters) into a single space by default.  There is no difference between `a word` and `a \n word` (or `a \r word` or `a \r\n word` for that matter) by default for *most* elements.  The solution is either to:

- Use a `<br>` element to add the break
- Set the style on your div to be [`whitespace: pre;`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/white-space)

Alternately, you can use a list (which is probably more semantic for your use case and should be preferred).

Comment: didn't know of `whitespace: pre;` that's pretty cool to keep HTML clean and the need of extra logic before the template rendering. I'd rather use `whitespace: pre-wrap` or `whitespace: pre-line` because I don't want long string/word to break out of the container.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

If you're rendering as HTML, you need to use a `<br>` tag instead of a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
dust.optimizers.format = function(ctx, node) { return node };
```

Look at  https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/wiki/Dust-Tutorial#controlling-whitespace-suppression

Comment: And be sure to call it BEFORE `dust.compileFn()` :)